# "How To Ask" text should link to help center, not faq

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, user-interface

Similar to my [question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189393/metas-how-to-ask-links-to-faq), Writers.SE's "*How To Ask*" text should link to the help center, rather than the FAQ:
[image: How To Ask: Writers.SO]

Just as it does in here on Writers Meta (which seems to be more up to date than SO's Meta):
[image: How To Ask: Meta.Writers.SO]

Comment: Worth noting that the `/faq` route now redirects appropriately to the help center, I'm going to find out what the status is of getting them changed, I believe it's like this on every site.

Comment: Confirmed, it's like this on every site _but_ SO/MSO, where it's the complete opposite. Looking into getting this fixed now.

Comment: @TimPost I checked it on every site I'm a member on before posting. [english.SE], [programmers.SE], [webapps.SE], and [codegolf.SE] are all fine, but [writers.SE] and [codereview.SE] (and probably others) look like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This section is a value that can be customized per site.  It looks like a small number of sites escaped the wrath of our mass replacement when the help center went live.  The offenders have been tracked down and eliminated with extreme...uh, SQL?

It should be correct on all sites now, thanks for letting us know.

Comment: Yes, it seems to have been fixed now. Thanks.